# Access an array in all views in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made an array in MY_Controller class placed on core folder. In its constructor i fetched records from db so as to make navigation menu in my views. Since i have different page layouts so i cannot call the same header view every where. for this reason i made a core class as per my understanding which i am not sure is right or not. below is the code for my controller

```
class MY_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Category_model');
        $data['parent'] = $this->Category_model->getParentCategories();
        $data['child'] = $this->Category_model->getChildCategories();
    }
}
```

my default controller is main

```
class Main extends MY_controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('home/footer');
    }
```

Now in my header view i am receiving undefined variable parent and child error. I want this two variables available in all the views so that i do not have to define those two variables in every controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
class MY_controller extends CI_Controller
{

    $commonData = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Category_model');
        $this->commonData['parent'] = $this->Category_model->getParentCategories();
        $this->commonData['child'] = $this->Category_model->getChildCategories();
    }
}
```

Then use `$this->comonData` in your `index` method instead of `$data` to pass to the `view`:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home/header', $this->comonData);
    $this->load->view('home/footer');
}
```

Now it'll be available in the `header` view and since it's at the top of other views then you may use it further, unless you override it with other value in any class.